# Round time in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I want to round time in milliseconds in a dataframe
My dataframe is :

```
   id             Time  
0   12    12:21:13.985    
1   21    12:21:15.236        
2   88    12:22:52.523    
3   32    12:25:26.023    
4   64    12:26:33.632
```

My desired dataframe:

```
   id             Time  
0   12        12:21:14    
1   21        12:21:15        
2   88        12:22:53    
3   32        12:25:26     
4   64        12:26:34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`to_datetime`** with **`round`** and **`strftime`**

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.round('1s').dt.time

   id      Time
0  12  12:21:14
1  21  12:21:15
2  88  12:22:53
3  32  12:25:26
4  64  12:26:34
```

Comment: You were right about using string. It is preferable to use time library. But I like alternatives :). Upvoted!

Comment: I was sure this was a duplicate of something, but the rounding to the second is what changes it from past questions I think.  I think your method could be easily adapted to check the first digit of the milliseconds to round it that way.

Comment: You could use `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.round('1s').dt.time` I think though. That was my first "intuition".